# OpenGL - How can I make the edges of this textured circle smoother?

Tags: opengl, c++, textures

I'm building a game and I've applied a certain texture (RAW file) to a circle (GL_POLYGON) in OpenGL. It loads correctly, with the right size and all, but the edges seem a bit jagged and I would prefer them smooth (without any evidence of a polygon being underneath).

[image: Right now it looks like this]

```
GLuint loadTex(int wrap){
GLuint texture;
int width, height;
BYTE * data;
FILE * file;

file = fopen( "tex.raw", "rb" );
if (file == NULL){
    std::cerr << "O ficheiro da textura não foi encontrado" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

width = 128;
height = 128;
data = (BYTE*)malloc( width * height * 3 );//Alocação do buffer

fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );//Ler dados da textura
fclose( file );

glGenTextures( 1, &texture );//Nome da textura
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );//Selecção da textura actual
glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );//Parâmetros da Textura
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrap ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrap ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP );
gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );

free(data);

return texture;
}


void drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, float aspectRatio){

GLuint t = loadTex(1);
float angle, radian, x, y, tx, ty, xcos, ysin;

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t);

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

for (angle=0.0; angle<360.0; angle+=2.0){
    radian = angle * (M_PI/180.0f);

    xcos = (float)cos(radian);
    ysin = (float)sin(radian);
    x = xcos * r  + cx;
    y = ysin * r*aspectRatio + cy;
    tx = xcos * 0.5 + 0.5;
    ty = ysin * 0.5 + 0.5;

    glTexCoord2f(tx, ty);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
}

glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Is this a problem from my texture file? Or is it from my code? I apply Line Smoothing before drawing anything (and it is being applied correctly in my lines I believe)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you never figured this out, you need to enable GL_BLEND and set both your blend equation and blend function to use transparency.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

also when you apply your texture you set the color format to GL_RGB when it should be RGBA, also why did you use gluBuild2DMipmaps instead of glTexImage2D, for your purposes you really don't need to use gluBuild2DMipmaps, but none the less the same applies,

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );
```

this should fix your problem with your code, sorry this is 4 years late, but still hope it helps (=

Answer (score 1):

It should be either from the image file itself, or from a shader which rejects all perfectly white pixels, or something like that, but since the shader isn't the simplest thing to implement, I'll bet it's the image file. I'll also bet you made or found this image with a white background, then tried to delete that white to make the background transparent. Unfortunately you deleted the pixels that are perfectly white, but the edge isn't perfectly sharp, and you missed some partially white pixels.

Those are the more certain bets I can make. Now I'll make another less certain bet: that you're using GIMP. If you're not, maybe you can adapt the instructions for another program.

You want to experiment with the tolerance on the selection wand, as well as selection feathering, and the color erase mode of the fill tool. Find whatever works best. Maybe take your current image with the transparent background, do alpha to selection, shrink selection by 1px, invert, then color erase white.

Comment: I've tried both with the white background and a transparent one and it has the same problem with both images. However, I can't save the image as a RAW file with transparency, because somehow it messes with the texture when it's loaded (probably needs some extra memory allocation to it?). 

I'm using Photoshop

Comment: Odd... What kind of blending are you using, if any at all? If you don't know what that is, then researching it might help you a lot. Otherwise, do you have a discard statement in your fragment shader? Did you make your own fragment shader in the first place?

Comment: I did not make any fragment shader. As for blending... I should research about it like you suggested (I'm a beginner) but I believe I used the regular and recommended code:

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not you texture, this should be solved when you put something in background, like texture or geometry, I had similar problem.